# how to know if UIButton titlelable.text changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, key-value-observing

I just want to know how can I fire some function when button title change ? 
i tried to use this command but nothing work :

```
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(function:) 
       forControl:UIControlEventValueChange];
```

Comment: [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA)

Comment: Use KVO ( add observer using KVO foe value change using KVO ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an observer in your viewcontroller that has an outlet to the button:

1. First add the observer (in viewDidLoad for example)

   ```
   [self.button addObserver:self 
                 forKeyPath:@"titleLabel.text" 
                    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
                    context:NULL];
   ```
2. Override default observer method on your viewcontroller

   ```
   - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                         ofObject:(id)object 
                           change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                          context:(void *)context {

       if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"titleLabel.text"]) {
           // Value changed
           UIButton *button = object;
           NSString *title = button.titleLabel.text;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Remove yourself as observer in the dealloc function

   ```
   [self.button removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"titleLabel.text"];
   ```

Comment: thanks so much it works fine but why the observer call twice ?

Comment: @user2978353 Try setting a breakpoint in the "observeValueForKeyPath"-method, then you can see for yourself which code sets the buttontitle. Probably, the value gets set from apple code (because you probably have a text set on on the button in .xib-file, and once from your code)

Answer (score 1):

Use `KVO` (ie. `Key-Value-Observer`) listen to the text property of the `UIButton's` `titleLabel`.
try below code

```
  [button.titleLabel addObserver:self 
                      forKeyPath:@"text" 
                         options: NSKeyValueChangeOldKey | NSKeyValueChangeNewKey 
                         context:nil];
```

Then implement the observer for it

```
      -(void)addObserver:(NSObject *)observer
              forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                 options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options
                 context:(void *)context{

                 // your code
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Logic is : Declare `UIButton` in **.h** file with it's property and use code in **.m** file

```
if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:updatedButtonTitleString])
{
  // title is same
}
else
{
  // title is updated
}
```